# What is the URL in opeshift for javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, openshift

I want to use external javascript libraries in openshift hosted account ? What is the URL I should refer to get the javascript files. ( I have stored the javascript files inside the project)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can refer js files using the local url system. As a example if you have those files in the same location you can refer using {path to file}/javascriptfile.js style

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../libraries/dhtmlxCalendar/dhtmlxCalendar/codebase/dhtmlxcalendar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../libraries/dhtmlxCalendar/dhtmlxCalendar/codebase/skins/dhtmlxcalendar_dhx_skyblue.css">
<script src="../../libraries/dhtmlxCalendar/dhtmlxCalendar/codebase/dhtmlxcalendar.js"></script>
```